# Fetch API getting php content instead of making a request

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

I have a React Component that uses js fetch API to get data from a PHP file.
The problem is that the promise returned contains the content of the PHP file instead of the JSON that I expected.
When I try to use `.json` at the promise it gives me an error which I think is caused by getting the contents of the PHP file.

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I have already tried the `header('Content-Type')` on both sides (js and php).

Here follows my code, if you could give me some help I would appreciate it, thanks.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const API = '../api/rest/balances.php';

export class Balance extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: '0.00000000'
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(API)
            .then(response => console.log(response.json()))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <span className="balance">{this.state.value}</span>
        )
    }
}
```

PHP

```
<?php

use TradingBot\Connections\Factory;

header("Content-Type: application/json");

session_start();

$jsonReturn = new stdClass();

if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {

    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'vendor' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'autoload.php';
    //Inclui os arquivos necessários
    //Cria um objeto conexão com o banco para o usuario
    $users = Factory::makeUsers();

    //Pega as credenciais da API
    $credentials = $users->GetCredentials($_SESSION['usuario']);

    //Cria a conexão com a Binance
    $api = new Binance\API($credentials->api_key, $credentials->api_secret);

    //Tenta adquirir o balanço da conta
    try {
        $balances = $api->balances();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $jsonReturn->error = $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }

    //Filtra os resultados diferentes de zero
    $available = array_filter($balances, function ($valor) {
        return $valor['available'] > 0;
    });

    $jsonReturn->saldo = $available;
    echo json_encode($jsonReturn);
    exit();
} else {
    $jsonReturn->error = "user not defined at session";
    echo json_encode($jsonReturn);
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: If you get the actual source of the PHP script, it means PHP is not running on your server.

Comment: Webserver and php are setup correctly? put `<?php phpinfo() ?>` in a php file and open it in the browser. What do you get?

Comment: But the error message doesn't really say that. It could also be an HTML formatted error which would also start with `<`, so just hit F12, and inspect the actual response to see what is going on. Also, debug PHP scripts by just calling them, not by calling them through a chunk of JavaScript and processing results that you didn't even check, because it's really hard and time consuming to debug like that. Zoom in on the error, and test only the relevant part.

Comment: `which I think` - browsers have a developer tools console and network tab - use these to see exactly what the server is sending for the request

Comment: Oh, I can see now that PHP cannot run at webpack dev server that I was actualy using. When I ran it on my apache server on localhost it worked!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
componentDidMount() {
      fetch(API)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => console.log(response))
}
```